# Walk through each column in a numpy matrix efficiently in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a very big two-dimensions array in Python, using `numpy` library. I want to walk through each column efficiently and check each time if elements are different from 0 to count their number in every column.

Suppose I have the following matrix.

```
M = array([[1,2], [3,4]])
```

The following code enables us to walk through each row efficiently, for example (it is not what I intend to do of course!):

```
for row_idx, row in enumerate(M):
    print "row_idx", row_idx, "row", row 
    for col_idx, element in enumerate(row):
        print "col_idx", col_idx, "element", element
        # update the matrix M: square each element
        M[row_idx, col_idx] = element ** 2
```

However, in my case I want to walk through each column efficiently, since I have a very big matrix.

I've heard that there is a very efficient way to achieve this using numpy, instead of my current code:

```
curr_col, curr_row = 0, 0
while (curr_col < numb_colonnes):
    result = 0
    while (curr_row < numb_rows):
        # If different from 0
        if (M[curr_row][curr_col] != 0):
           result += 1
        curr_row += 1
    .... using result value ...
    curr_col += 1
    curr_row = 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to clean up the indentation.

Comment: Re your first code block, it can be substituted by the single statement `M=M*M`

Comment: Indentation corrected, thank's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you showed us, you treat `numpy`'s arrays as lists and for what you can see, it works!  But arrays are not lists, and while you can treat them as such it wouldn't make sense to use arrays, or even `numpy`.

To really exploit the usefulness of `numpy` you have to operate directly on arrays, writing, e.g.,

```
M = M*M
```

when you want to square the elements of an array and using the rich set of `numpy` functions to operate directly on arrays.

That said, I'll try to get a bit closer to your problem... 
If your intent is to count the elements of an array that are different from zero, you can use the `numpy` function `sum`.

Using `sum`, you can obtain the sum of all the elements in an array, or you can sum across a particular axis.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(((3,4),(5,6)))
print np.sum(a) # 18
print np.sum(a, axis=0) # [8, 10]
print np.sum(a, axis=1) # [7, 11]
```

Now you are protesting: I don't want to sum the elements, I want to count the non-zero elements... but

1. if you write a logical test on an array, you obtain an array of booleans, e.g, we want to test which elements of `a` are even

   ```
   print a%2==0
   # [[False  True]
   #  [False  True]]
   ```
2. `False` is zero and `True` is one, at least when we sum it...

   ```
   print np.sum(a%2==0) # 2
   ```

   or, if you want to sum over a column, i.e., the index that changes is the 0-th

   ```
   print np.sum(a%2==0, axis=0) # [0 2]
   ```

   or sum across a row

   ```
   print np.sum(a%2==0, axis=1) # [1 1]
   ```

To summarize, for your particular use case

```
by_col = np.sum(M!=0, axis=0)
# use the counts of non-zero terms in each column, stored in an array
...

# if you need the grand total, use sum again
total = np.sum(by_col)
```